# How to integrate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a -b\cos x}}$

Tags: calculus

Does someone know how to evaluate $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a -b\cos x}}dx$? I can't seem to integrate it through normal means. Any insight is helpful!

Comment: With elliptic functions, maybe?

Comment: Which "normal means" did you try? BTW, [here's a LaTeX (well, "MathJax") guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This one requires elliptic functions. Go to integral-calculator.com and they will solve it for you.

Comment: @J.G  I only know elementry methods and I'm trying to wrap my head around substitutions (I'm new to this), but this was actually a physics problem I was trying to solve but got stuck at a similar equation (I tried to use a and b to generalize it so incase someone else gets stuck they can come across this hopefully)

Comment: @Dp03 Yep, [it comes up in physics all right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Arbitrary-amplitude_period).

Answer (score 1):

We need an [incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind),$$F(\varphi,\,k):=\int_0^\varphi\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}},$$in terms of which$$\begin{align}\int_0^x\frac{dt}{\sqrt{a-b\cos t}}&=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{\sqrt{a-b+2b\sin^2\frac{t}{2}}}\\&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{a-b}}\int_0^{x/2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2b}{a-b}\sin^2\theta}}\\&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{a-b}}F\left(\frac{x}{2},\,\sqrt{\frac{2b}{a-b}}\right).\end{align}$$